# how to display a text with tags in jsp

Tags: html, jsp, htmltextwriter

I want to display a text called

```
"welcome<to>Jsp"
```

In page source also i'm seeing as "welcomeJsp"

But in HTML its displaying as "welcomeJsp" alone. Please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape these characters..

```
welcome&lt;to&gt;Jsp
```

I would advice using Apache's [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) class(available in org.apache.commons.lang ) function `escapeHtml()` for escaping HTML.

`StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml("welcome<to>Jsp")`

Answer (score 1):

```
"welcome&lt;to&gt;Jsp"


&gt; (greater than) - (>)
&lt; (less than)    - (<)
```

These characters need to be encoded this way to actually display them.

Answer (score 1):

Use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) [`<c:out>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/out.html) tag or [`fn:escapeXml()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/escapeXml.fn.html) function.

```
<c:out value="welcome<to>Jsp" />
```

or

```
${fn:escapeXml('welcome<to>Jsp')}
```

You can even use it on model values.

```
<c:out value="${bean.property}" />
```

or

```
${fn:escapeXml(bean.property)}
```

Those two should by the way *always* be used when it concerns user-controlled input, you're otherwise totally open to XSS attack holes. See also [our JSP wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) and [What is the general concept behind XSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233015/what-is-the-general-concept-behind-xss/2233110#2233110)

Answer (score 0):

I just added spaces :)

```
<body bgcolor="#333" text="#fff">
<!-- jsp expression -->
<p>Expression < % = new java.util.Date() % ></p>
<p> <%= new java.util.Date() %></p>
<!-- jsp Scriptlet -->
<p>Scriptlet < % Java code 1 to many lines % ></p>
<!-- jsp Declaration -->
<p>Declaration  < % ! variable or method declaration %></p>
<p>JSP comment < %-- --%></p>
```